# MVC Error handling using Action Filters

Tags: model-view-controller, error-handling, action-filter, handleerror

I would like to know best practice to handle exceptions.

I have 3 types of exception flows

1)  Warnings: - In this I am required to display the partial data received from the service and also the error code/ message.
2)  Business errors: - In this no data just the error code is received but I want to display the view with all the controls (e.g. dropdown) and the error message. 
3)  System failure errors: - In this scenario I would like to redirect to custom error page.

I am using Using ASP.NET MVC and lang is C#

Comment: What exactly do you want to know, and what language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like (1) and (2) probably shouldn't be exceptions. If you can easily handle the error and present a page to the user and let them continue, I wouldn't use exceptions. These sound more like data or validation issues which could be handled in code without exceptions.